# Referencing superview's methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm making an application in Xcode, and running into some problems. I'm using the GameKit framework to allow for bluetooth communication between two iOS devices. The application is setup so that one of the devices is the "master" and the other is the "slave," changing it's screen content based on data received from the "master" device. The user can select whether to be the master or the slave, and when that choice is made, the other device automatically becomes the opposite role. This is all done in one view controller class. When a role is chosen, a subview is added to the baseViewController.

What my problem is, is that when the subview that is added, I would like to be able to send data using the methods in the baseViewController class. With the current setup, the device invoking the action `becomeMaster:sender` crashes.

What I've tried so far is,

BaseViewController:

```
-(IBAction)becomeMaster:(id)sender {
    [self dataToSend:@"slave"]; //tells peer device to become slave, since this device is master
    masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [masterViewController setBaseViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:masterViewController.view];
}

-(void)dataToSend:(NSString *)direction {   
    //—-convert an NSString object to NSData—-  
    NSData* data;   
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:direction];  
    data = [str dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];  
    [self mySendDataToPeers:data];
}

-(void)dataToSend:(NSString *)direction {   
    //—-convert an NSString object to NSData—-  
    NSData* data;   
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:direction];  
    data = [str dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];  
    [self mySendDataToPeers:data];
}

 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession:(GKSession *)session context:(void *)context {   
    //—-convert the NSData to NSString—-    
    NSString* str;  
    str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [self useReceivedData:str];
    [str release];
}

-(void)useReceivedData:(NSString *)str {
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"forward"]) {
        [slaveViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

MasterViewController:

```
-(void)setBaseViewController:(BaseViewController *)bvc {
    baseViewController = bvc;
}

-(IBAction)goForward:(id)sender {
    actionLabel.text = @"goingForward";
    [baseViewController dataToSend:@"forward"];
}
```

Most of that code is part of the standard Apple documentation/examples, but I included it for understanding the flow of logic.

I believe the problem originates to with the `becomeMaster:sender` and `setBaseViewController:bvc` methods. Could anyone help fix? Thanks so much!

Comment: There's also a SlaveViewController subview as well. Also, there are no build time errors (I believe I set up the instance variables and synthesized them correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of crash are you getting? `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? Try turning on `NSZombieEnabled` in your executable's arguments. It's difficult to say what could be causing the crash, but you might try changing your `setBaseViewController:` implementation to this:

```
-(void)setBaseViewController:(BaseViewController *)bvc {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"baseViewController"];
    [baseViewController autorelease]
    baseViewController = [bvc retain];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"baseViewController"];
}
```

And add `[baseViewController release];` to `MasterViewController`'s `-dealloc` method.

Keep in mind that it's not entirely necessary to have a custom setter for `baseViewController`.  If you have the following property declaration in your header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) BaseViewController *baseViewController;
```

And you use `@synthesize baseViewController`, the `-setBaseViewController:` method is already generated for you, with key-value observing support built in. If you aren't familiar with Objective-C 2.0 properties, I suggest reading [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Comment: I'm somewhat noobish with memory management, so here's to hoping this doesn't sound dumb. Did you mean to say add `[bvc release]` to the `-dealloc` method? Because from where I'm sitting, it looks like bvc would end up at a +1 and seeing as how `baseViewController` is a ivar, I already had it released in the `-dealloc`, meaning it would  be at -1 or possibly something else when you take into account the autorelease. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked like a charm! However, I want to be sure I'm not leaking memory somewhere. Just to check, this is what my masterViewController class has in it: a declared ivar baseViewController, synthesized in the .m file, the setBaseViewController method exactly as you posted, and the `-dealloc` method with only a single release of baseViewController. Is this correct?

Comment: No worries. Keep in mind that all of these variables are actually _pointers_, and that the `-dealloc` method has no access to the _variable_ named `bvc`, but rather the object referenced by `baseViewController`, which I'm assuming is an instance variable of `MasterViewController`. When you set `baseViewController = [bvc retain];`, you're increasing the retain count of the _object_ by 1, and setting the _variable_ `baseViewController` to point to that object. So releasing `baseViewController` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So it would be correct to have 1 release or releases of baseViewController in `-dealloc`?

Comment: Yes, if you use the method implementation above, include 1 release of `baseViewController` in `-dealloc`.